# Proxy within a proxy using SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel

There's a problem with Iranian internet connections in the few past days. Yesterday, one of my friends said I can connect to the global internet (we have access to Iranian websites which hosted inside Iran) by using this on our business servers :

```
ssh user@ip -D 9595
```

And then, setting that proxy on the system or the browser. This is how I'm here. But for more safety, I actually want to do it a layer further, the business server is located in Iran and we also have another server which is located in Germany. Is there anyway to do a proxy through that one, from my current one?

P.S : I can't directly connect to our Germany's server.